# Compare in Assembly language

Tags: loops, assembly, compare

I need to compare if the next character of string is the end of line (`$`) or not. This is my code:

```
data segment
string db 256 dup ('$')
data ends
...
n_loop equ 256
    mov cx, n_loop
    mov bx, offset string
start_loop:
    mov dl, [bx] 
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    mov dl, 32 
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    inc bx
    cmp word ptr [bx], '$' ; this is where I think I must to compare it
    loopne start_loop
    je fin
fin:
    ...
```

But unforlunetly I'm too new to Assembly language and my code doesn't work. And for true I even don't know if I'm right with idea to compare `bx` with `$`.

Comment: You're comparing a 16-bit value (word ptr destination of BX) with an 8-bit immediate of "$".  That's probably not doing exactly what you intend...

Comment: Oh, you are right! `cmp byte ptr [bx], '$'` works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear it's working now, I made it an answer too.  :-)

Comment: Can you pelase tell me is this right way to find the end of line? Because I think there should be some more system characters

Comment: Nothing else obviously wrong is jumping out at me.  I'd recommend running it in a debugger so you can verify though.  Appears you're in a DOS environment, so you should have "debug" available to you.  It can display memory regions so you can verify the contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing a 16-bit value (word ptr destination of BX) with an 8-bit immediate of "$". That's probably not doing exactly what you intend...